# Is smoking sinful?

Tags: sin

I know among some Christian groups (e.g. Laestadians) almost everyone smokes, while some other groups are very strict about it. However, the Bible doesn't have cigarettes.

Is smoking sinful?

Comment: I'm not sure that "is x sinful?" is a constructive line of questions to follow.

Comment: [Are "is X a sin" questions on topic?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/245)

Comment: I came to the conclusion the community is better off without this question, so voted to close myself. http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/how-should-a-christian-evaluate-whether-a-particular-action-a-sin-or-not is a better question.

Comment: See: [How should a christian evaluate whether a particular action a sin or not?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1011)

Comment: See this link under Bible Questions Answered -> Is Smoking a Sin? (by Jehovah's Witnesses) https://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/smoking-sin/

Answer (score 10):

There are some questions you can ask yourself about smoking. For example:

1. Does smoking show respect or disrespect for God's gift of life?? <sup>[Acts 17:24,25](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts%2017:24-25&version=NIV), [Philippians 1:10,11](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Philippians%201:10-11&version=NIV)</sup>
2. Is it consistent with what God requires Christians to render to him? <sup>[Romans 12:1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Rom.%2012:1&version=NIV)</sup>

   - Is it consistent for a person to present himself to God for sacred service and then deliberately to ruin his health?
3. Does it violate the divine requirement that we love our neighbor? <sup>[James 2:7](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jas.%202:8&version=NIV), [Matthew 7:12](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%207:12&version=NIV)</sup>
4. Does smoking contaminate the body? <sup>[2 Corinthians 7:1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Cor%207:1&version=NIV)</sup>

Comment: How about generalizing this answer for this question: [What makes any particular action a sin or not?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1011)

Answer (score 3):

Good question! I enjoy a cigarette every once and a while, socially.

The Bible does not forbid smoking "anything" directly, so we'll need to look and see if we can find any other qualities of smoking forbidden.

### Generalized

At the most general level we can equate cigarettes with damage to your body, thus this verse stands to teach us.

> **1 Cor 6:19-20** (NIV)
>
> Do you not know that your body is a temple of the Holy Spirit, who is
> in you, whom you have received from God? You are not your own; you
> were bought at a price. Therefore honour God with your body.

And this warning about gratifying the cravings of our sinful nature.

> **Eph 2:1-3** (NIV)
>
> As for you, you were dead in your transgressions and sins, in which
> you used to live when you followed the ways of this world and of the
> ruler of the kingdom of the air, the spirit who is now at work in
> those who are disobedient. All of us also lived among them at one
> time, gratifying the cravings of our sinful nature and following its
> desires and thoughts. Like the rest, we were by nature objects of
> wrath.

Here's the stand that I take: "In moderation" God did not come down to tell you that you cannot enjoy life, but instead He came down to teach you how to love others. I would say that smoking hurts nobody but yourself, thus you are not breaking the law of love. In moderation smoking will not kill you.

> Eph 5:18 (TCN)
>
> Do not drink wine to excess... but seek to be filled with the Spirit
> of God.

Comment: " I would say that smoking hurts nobody but yourself" so second hand smoke need not apply?

Comment: that's debatable. you could smoke in the alley with the rest of us and only be sharing :)

Comment: I'm partial to the idea that "it's OK to hurt myself so long as I doesn't hurt anyone else" (libertarianism) is the opposite of the commandment to love (and mixed with despair) because A.) you assume your existence is not a blessing to those around you and B.) because you take for granted the existence God has given you.

Comment: So... you give two quotations that would lead most people to conclude that smoking (regular smoking, not just one cigar a week or such) is a sin.  But then turn around and claim it isn't.  One wonders...  oh, and don't compare it to wine, because moderation with nicotine is *much* harder.

Comment: I could have equated these verses to "is not getting up when the alarm clock goes off at 5am a sin?" they are generalized verses.