# Is there a biblical ban on running a casino?

Tags: biblical-basis, sin, christian-living, money

This is a spin on the question [Is there a Biblical ban on gambling?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/is-there-a-biblical-ban-on-gambling/2068#2068)

Is opening a casino considered a "shady business" a Christian should not be involved in? (Yes, let's assume it's perfectly legal.)

This question seeks to involve both the offline and online worlds (online poker, [online lottery](http://www.neopets.com/games/game.phtml?game_id=58), [online dice](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/18rh3v/how_does_provably_fair_gambling_work/), etc).

Comment: I do not believe that there is a single answer which would work for all denominations.  Is there a specific denomination which you are concerned about?  Some *could* call bingo gambling and therefore some halls *could* be considered pseudo casinos.

Comment: @TheFreemason it's tagged biblical-basis that becomes the *de facto* doctrinal scoping here. That said, there's a good point here. The Bible isn't (and shouldn't be read as) a legal document. You're not going to find "don't own a casino" in the pages. What you may find is principals that will guide you to a decision yes or no. Those principals are subject to a high level of interpretation which may mean that a biblical argument can be made from both sides

Comment: @Pacerier what I'm pointing out is that this kind of question is only *barely* within bounds here. And any answer you get here should be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: @Pacerier you'd ask within a tradition/theological POV or ask for the basis of a specific position rather than asking for both positions

Comment: @Pacerier no. not really. But sort of. How one reads the bible both informs and is informed by their theological POV. Biblical Basis is *not* a theological POV, it's one in a de facto sense here, but it's not really one.

Comment: @Pacerier if you're looking for "arguments from both sides" then there cannot possibly be a single answer to your question w/o bias.  As much as I have often tried and failed, SO / SE are not the proper format for these types of debates - no matter how tempting that it may be.

Answer (score 3):

Christianity is freedom, freedom from the Law (10 commandements, which created the notion of sin, without that law, there is no sin), freedom from the judgement. But a christians are a different species, they are not human, they are christian, not born through Adam but born through Christ (by the baptism), as an apple tree only produce apples what we produce cannot be called sin (for we don't belong that category), Adam 's sin is not in us, at least for those who really believe (faith is not mesurable).

I'm saying you are free to run a casino. But you will be naturally incline to stop yourself those of your consumers that are addicted and ruining their lifes and their families with gambling. Nobody can tell you what are you doing is wrong, but same as an apple tree that only can produce apples, your nature (you) will feel bad from continuing to take money from those who are addicted gamblers (and are having problems because of that, if your consumer is a billionaire and gambling is something he like to do and have no problems from that, it's not a bad addiction). So if you can run a casino, with our chistian nature's sense of justice it will be a healthy casino, where people have a good time and feel good, so if you can do so, just go for it, christian style ! you have no law, no ban, we just are christians. Be bless.

Comment: Poetic pastoral advise with no references.

Answer (score 2):

A casino in itself is not bad, but it is a flowing river for the love of money, and I would not want to be a cause for others to love money.

> For the love of money is a root of all kinds of evil. Some people, eager for money, have wandered from the faith and pierced themselves with many griefs. (1 Timothy 6:10, NIV).

God tells us not to cause a brother or sister to stumble (Romans 14:13). If a "weak" brother whose conscience will not allow him to gamble, even though he *wants to*, sees a "strong" brother gambling, and this brother's conscience allows him to gamble, the weaker brother could very well stumble and be drawn back into doing something he knows he shouldn't do, thus violating his conscience. The stronger brother would thereby become a stumbling block to the weaker brother.

> We put no stumbling block in anyone's path, so that our ministry will not be discredited. (2 Corinthians 6:3, NIV)

Our lives should be a ministry for others, in Christ Jesus.

Answer (score 1):

The  last  six  commandments  address  man's  relationship  to  man.

Acts 5;27-29  And  when  they  had  brought  them,  they  set  them  before  the  council:  and  the  high  priest  ask  them  28  Saying,  Did  not  we  straitly  command  you  that  ye  should  teach  in  this  name?  and,  behold,  ye  have  filled  Jerusalem  with  your  doctrine,  and  intend to  bring  this  man's  blood  upon  us.  29  Then  Peter  and  the  other  apostles  answered  and  said,  We  ought  to  obey  God  rather  than  men.

Exodus 20;17  Thou  shalt  not  covet  thy  neighbour's  house,  thou  shalt  not  covet  thy  neighbour's  wife,  nor  his  manservant,  nor  his  maidservant,  nor  his  ox,  nor  his  ass,  nor  anything  that  is  thy  neighbours.

1 Timothy 6;3-11
    3  If  any  man  teach  otherwise,  and  consent  not  to  wholesome  words,  even  the  words  of  our  LORD  Jesus  Christ,  and  to  the  doctrine  which  is according  to  godliness;
    4  He  is  proud,  knowing  nothing,  but  doting  about  questions  and  strifes  of  words,  whereof  cometh  envy,  strife,  railings,  evil  surmising,
    5  Pervese  disputings  of  men  of  corrupt  minds,  and  destitute  of  the  truth,  supposing  that  gain  is  godliness:  for  such  withdraw  thyself.
    6  But  godliness  with  contentment  is  gain.
    7  For  we  brought  nothing  into  this  world,  and  certian  we  can  carry  nothing  out.
    8  And  having  food  and  raiment  let  us  be  therewith  content.
    9  But  they  that  will  be  rich  fall  into  temptation  and  a  snare,  and  into  many  foolish  and  hurtful  lusts,  which  drown  men in destruction and  perdition.
   10 For  the  love  of  money  is  the  root  of  all  evil:  which  while  some  coveted  after,  they  have  erred  from  the  faith,  and  pierced  themselves  through  with  many  sorrrows.
   11  But  thou  O  man  of  God,  flee  these  things;  and  follow  after  righteousness,  godliness,  faith,  love,  patience,  meekness.

```
1
```