# Why is smoking a sin?

Tags: sin

Many Christians are saying that smoking is sin. However, there are no cigarettes in the Bible. Personally, I don't smoke because the cigarette cover says *"Smoking is injurious to health"*. Hence, I consider it foolishness to harm yourself. Moreover, I tried to smoke once but I choked and never tried again. There is really no point in inhaling smokes.

Here are my questions to those Christian groups who believe that smoking is a sin.

1. What is the argument that smoking is sin?
2. What Bible verses are used to infer that smoking is sin?
3. Is smoking a sin just because it is injurious to health? If so, it would be a sin to keep on eating fats when the doctor says not to and you can't resist it.

Comment: The answers at [Is smoking sinful?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/is-smoking-sinful) answer this.

Comment: @AndrewLeach that question is closed, and this one is appropriately scoped (those that consider smoking to be sinful). I'd prefer to leave this one open if we can and we'll reclose the other as a duplicate and possibly merge.

Comment: This question is in the reopen queue. I'd vote to reopen if it were a more focused Biblical basis question (which would require edits, but not *huge* edits), but with the question being so old, I think that should be the OP's responsibility if he wants it.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude Hmm, okay.  I'd have thought that moderate editing of a closed question with an absentee OP without breaking answers would be acceptable.  Not a big deal though – my instigating motivation for reopening was that the system prevents me from casting a delete vote on the target of a duplicate.  If we do ever get a well-defined biblical basis question on this subject we can reevaluate, perhaps.

Comment: @Nathaniel I think that's acceptable, but my concern about others doing it on old questions is a potential lack of buy-in by the OP. But if someone else edited it well, I'd probably vote to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

**What is the argument that smoking is sin? / What Bible verses are used to infer that smoking is sin?**

There are multiple reasons why smoking can be seen as a sin. And some of the reasons appeared because we only started to learn some things about smoking in the last hundred years.

1. Smoking is proven to be unhealthy, thus when smoking you [are willingly destroying your body](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%203:17&version=ESV)
2. Nicotine and the habit of smoking is addicting just like gambling or alcohol. And addiction can be seen as [a devil you need to resist](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=James%204:7&version=ESV) or a [temptation to be avoiding](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2010:13&version=ESV). Also an addiction overpowers you and [becomes your master.](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%206:24&version=ESV)
3. Some people are trying to look cool and [conform](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%2012:2&version=ESV) to their smoking environment.

But the first point is the most suggested when talking about smoking being a sin.

**Is smoking a sin just because it is injurious to health? If so, it would be a sin to keep on eating fats when the doctor says not to and you can't resist it.**

This actually a general social issue which is invisibly linked to it being a sin or not.

People say to each other all the time, even to strangers: *"Smoking is bad for you!, Stop smoking!"*

This is social acceptable, but ask yourself if you see a fat man it is social acceptable to say to him:

*"Stop eating, so much, it's unhealthy!"*

Well, no. Not yet.

The same reason why it's social acceptable to call someone out on their smoking, is the reason we can call someone out using the bible as a weapon against an unhealthy habit *smoking* which can be seen a sin.

Because many Christian parent's don't want their kids to smoke it's easy to grab the bible and call it a sin. because it's unhealthy. But it wouldn't be very social acceptable to grab the same bible and call someone out because he's fat.

The spirit of time changes a lot, the German's have a word for this [zeitgeist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeitgeist).

Somewhere in the future you will probably see this happening.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This doesn't really have much to do with your answer, but I find that sharing the following tends to help new visitors avoid mistaking the purpose of this site. I do hope to see more from you!  When you get a chance, please see [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me and for the links.  Was my answer in your eyes acceptable,  any suggestions?  I'm a SE enthousiast trying to learn and spread my own knowledge an opinions on different matters.

Comment: @TimDev it shades a bit towards the truth side rather than presenting the evidence and letting the user judge (the question asks for the assumption that it is sinful and the rationale thereof), but overall it's a good effort. Thanks for contributing